# R converts date from yyyy-mm-dd to long date format while adding to Time series object

Tags: r, date

```
DataSTP2 <- read.csv("/Users/mass/Desktop/DatasetforR.csv", stringsAsFactors = F, na.strings = c(NA,"NA", " NA", "-", "NT")) 
class(DataSTP2$Month)
DataSTP2_omit <- na.omit(DataSTP2)
DataSTP2$Month <- as.Date(DataSTP2$Month, origin="1899-12-30" )
class(DataSTP2$Month)
STP.ts <- ts(data = DataSTP2, frequency = 12)

ggplot(data = DataSTP2, aes(x = Month, y = pH_in))+ ylab('pH') + geom_line(aes(y = pH_in), colour="blue") + geom_point() +geom_line(aes(y = pH_out), color="red") +geom_point() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

The command on 6th line converts the date from 2018-12-01 to 17866, I don't want that to happen please can some one help me figure it out?

**Edit**:

| Month | pH_in | pH_out |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-12-01 | 7.6 | 7.5 |
| 2019-01-01 | 7.8 | 7.6 |

A reference to the data I have been working with.

````
head(dput(DataSTP2),20) 
structure(list(Month = structure(c(17866, 17897, 17928, 17956, 
17987, 18017, 18048, 18078, 18109, 18140, 18170, 18201, 18231, 
18262, 18293, 18322, 18353, 18383, 18414, 18444, 18475), class = "Date"), 
    pH_in = c(7.52, 7.56, 7.62, 7.48, 7.61, 7.58, 7.67, 7.77, 
    7.65, 7.87, 7.84, 8.01, 7.83, 7.77, 7.75, 7.62, 7.58, 7.62, 
    7.34, 7.66, 7.56), pH_out = c(7.44, 7.31, 7.38, 7.31, 7.48, 
    7.62, 7.59, 7.72, 7.58, 7.74, 7.76, 7.66, 7.74, 7.7, 7.7, 
    7.6, 7.7, 7.7, 7.5, 7.3, 7.4), TSS_in = c(567.71, 647.55, 
    555.57, 537.35, 530.8, 449.87, 430.53, 433.42, 410.17, 530, 
    555, 662.9, 708.26, 674.77, 603.24, 602.17, 517, 452.5, 467.14, 
    484.67, 392), TSS_out = c(19.65, 23.06, 16.64, 11.06, 13.7, 
    12.55, 9.83, 15.74, 14.23, 14, 12.16, 11.41, 13.19, 13, 15.1, 
    14.5, 13, 11.5, 10.9, 12.7, 13), COD_in = c(681.87, 805.42, 
    799.43, 789.35, 865.4, 822.87, 718.17, 714.83, 632.77, 735, 
    762, 798.13, 830.53, 812.87, 849.64, 869.29, 788, 688, 712.66, 
    753.47, 600.6), COD_out = c(59.29, 67.55, 61.86, 56.57, 56.63, 
    58.5, 50.62, 55.49, 56.32, 61, 53.47, 62.01, 62.97, 80.1, 
    58.3, 58.2, 54, 50.4, 48.5, 56.3, 57.2), BOD3_in = c(187.84, 
    326.23, 316.46, 321.45, 352.03, 327, 334.97, 343.23, 320.33, 
    267, 276, 283.46, 268.71, 272.26, 277.92, 277.33, NA, NA, 
    223.75, 246.54, 186), BOD3_out = c(15.42, 14.45, 13.25, 12.19, 
    11.6, 10.79, 10.1, 11.23, 11.37, 9.4, 9.58, 10.62, 10.05, 
    9.8, 10, 10.1, NA, NA, 8.3, 11.7, 11), OG_in = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 0.27, 0.21, 0.23, 0.26, 0.22, 0.21, 0.24, 0.26, 
    0.26, 0.26, 0.26, NA, NA, 0.23, 0.23, 0.2), OG_out = c("›", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, "0.11", "0.08", "0.12", "0.10", "0.148", 
    "0.11", "0.09", "0.09", "0.1", "0.1", "0.2", NA, NA, "0.1", 
    "0.1", "0.1")), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = "data.frame")
     ```   Month pH_in pH_out TSS_in TSS_out COD_in COD_out BOD3_in BOD3_out OG_in OG_out
1  2018-12-01  7.52   7.44 567.71   19.65 681.87   59.29  187.84    15.42    NA      ›
2  2019-01-01  7.56   7.31 647.55   23.06 805.42   67.55  326.23    14.45    NA   <NA>
3  2019-02-01  7.62   7.38 555.57   16.64 799.43   61.86  316.46    13.25    NA   <NA>
4  2019-03-01  7.48   7.31 537.35   11.06 789.35   56.57  321.45    12.19    NA   <NA>
5  2019-04-01  7.61   7.48 530.80   13.70 865.40   56.63  352.03    11.60    NA   <NA>
6  2019-05-01  7.58   7.62 449.87   12.55 822.87   58.50  327.00    10.79  0.27   0.11
7  2019-06-01  7.67   7.59 430.53    9.83 718.17   50.62  334.97    10.10  0.21   0.08
8  2019-07-01  7.77   7.72 433.42   15.74 714.83   55.49  343.23    11.23  0.23   0.12
9  2019-08-01  7.65   7.58 410.17   14.23 632.77   56.32  320.33    11.37  0.26   0.10
10 2019-09-01  7.87   7.74 530.00   14.00 735.00   61.00  267.00     9.40  0.22  0.148
11 2019-10-01  7.84   7.76 555.00   12.16 762.00   53.47  276.00     9.58  0.21   0.11
12 2019-11-01  8.01   7.66 662.90   11.41 798.13   62.01  283.46    10.62  0.24   0.09
13 2019-12-01  7.83   7.74 708.26   13.19 830.53   62.97  268.71    10.05  0.26   0.09
14 2020-01-01  7.77   7.70 674.77   13.00 812.87   80.10  272.26     9.80  0.26    0.1
15 2020-02-01  7.75   7.70 603.24   15.10 849.64   58.30  277.92    10.00  0.26    0.1
16 2020-03-01  7.62   7.60 602.17   14.50 869.29   58.20  277.33    10.10  0.26    0.2
17 2020-04-01  7.58   7.70 517.00   13.00 788.00   54.00      NA       NA    NA   <NA>
18 2020-05-01  7.62   7.70 452.50   11.50 688.00   50.40      NA       NA    NA   <NA>
19 2020-06-01  7.34   7.50 467.14   10.90 712.66   48.50  223.75     8.30  0.23    0.1
20 2020-07-01  7.66   7.30 484.67   12.70 753.47   56.30  246.54    11.70  0.23    0.1
````

Comment: Can you provide sample data so we can see the data structure you are working with? See groans on minimal reproducible example

Comment: Pkumar I tried the code as you suggested, but still when I run it I get the date as 17866

Comment: @SWAPNILMEENA, Please do a `head(dput(yourdataframe),20)` then copy and paste that in the question (for 20 records) , It will help people to understand your problem more...

Comment: @SWAPNILMEENA, Use this: `ts(DataSPT2[,c('ph_in', 'ph_out')], start = c(2018, 12), frequency = 12)`

Comment: @PKumar Please check the head(dput(),20)